# How to access a URL which needs authentication in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, url

Currently I am loading an image from URL in my iPhone app, which is working fine. But now i want to access a protected URL. Please guide me with a piece of code that how can i access URL with credentials(username/password).

The simple code through which my app loaded the image from URL is given Below

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.somedirectory.com"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
    [Pic setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some third party library like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which makes it very easy.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```

Or you can use `NSURLConnection` class, but authentication implementation is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Look For these two callbacks

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    // IF to handle NTLM authentication.
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM])
        return YES;  

    // Mostly sent by IIS. 
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        return YES;

    return NO;
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge 
{   
    if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqual:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM]) 
    {
        [[challenge sender]  useCredential:[NSURLCredential 
                                                credentialWithUser:Username 
                                                password:password
                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]
                    forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } 
    else if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqual:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
          [[challenge sender]  useCredential:[NSURLCredential 
                                                credentialWithUser:Username  
                                                password:password 
                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]
                    forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } 
    else 
    {  
        [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not call the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge call back.